# How to make .net regex start searching from the end of the last match?

Tags: regex, unityscript

l'm new to Regex. Currently I'm trying to get all consequences of symbols without spaces from a string and to get null when they end.

```
var pattern:Regex=new Regex("[^ ]+");
    var s:String;
    for(var i:int=0;i<10;++i)//10 is for debugging because otherwise it will never end
    {
        s=pattern.Match("speed movement_vector Rigidbody walk_mode").Value;
        if(!s)
            break;
        Debug.Log(s);
    }
```

This finds only 'speed'.

[In this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) I've found G command which finds occurrence exactly after the last match, i.e. it cannot skip spacebar.

Besides, I don't understand it, because my pattern

```
var pattern:Regex=new Regex("\G\[^ ]+");
```

only throws errors about "Unexpected character G".

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use `yourString.Split(' ')`?

Comment: You don't need the `\ ` after `G`.

Comment: var pattern:Regex=new Regex("\G\\\[^ ]+"); this throws the same error

Comment: @Andrew Morton. I thought that regexp is faster, isn't it?

Comment: @user2136963 No, it isn't.

Comment: Wow, this (http://jsperf.com/regex-vs-split/2) shows, that Match version can be even significantly slower. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is because `\` is an escape character in both unityscript and regex. To fix this, add another `\` before the first one (the second one should be unnecessary):

```
var pattern:Regex=new Regex("\\G[^ ]+");
```